# What decides the parameters to pass in to the AsynTask class <>?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am relatively a newbie in android though have intermediate knowledge of Java. I am trying to understand

```
AsyncTask<>
```

I notice different parameters are passed e.g

```
AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean>
AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap>
```

into the angle brackets. Please What should or can those parameters be? Thanks Community.

Comment: That depends upon the declaration of type parameter of that class. How does it look like?

Comment: Whatever you want.  You need to understand how generics work.

Comment: Take a look at generics, might shed some light. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: You decide it. Have a look at the explaination in the ref page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Link to android's explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Look at "AsyncTask's generic types".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first param goes to `doInBackground`, the second to `onProgressUpdate`, the third parameter is what your `doInBackground` returns and it goes to `onPostExecute`